# Be able to get a directory name which is randomly generate

Tags: javascript

I use this javascript function to work on a XML Document :

```
$.get('./cliLog.xml', function(xml) {
 //some code
});
```

The problem is that actually the "cliLog.xml" is inside a directory which has a name like :

"cliLogging-_value_generate_".

I would like to be able to get the cliLog.xml by only using the part name "cliLogging-" of the directory name.

Something like :

```
$.get('../cliLogging-*/cliLog.xml', function(xml) {
  //some code
});
```

But the "cliLogging-*" doesn't work :( ...

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: as far as I know, you need to have a server side processing language to pass in the filenames to your javascript, either that, or create a hardcoded array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how is the value generated? if it's generated on the server side you could just print it at desired position, otherwise if it's generated through javascript even though it's possible it's not optimal to just print it, since it leaves room for alot of securit issues.

Javascript Version:

```
$.get('../cliLogging-'+variable+'/cliLog.xml', function(xml) {
  //some code
});
```

PHP Version

```
$.get('../cliLogging-'<?=$variable;?>'/cliLog.xml', function(xml) {
  //some code
});
```

Alt.

```
//if the string is assigned to a variable
$string ="$.get('../cliLogging-".$variable."/cliLog.xml', function(xml) {
  //some code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a server side API for that, which would probably have security issues.

Comment: well since javascript is rendered on the front end, its quite easy to edit the value that's assign to the variable, but that doesn't apply to the server side, if not they're depended on some user inputs and such, more or less as long as something is depended on the user you can never rely on it.

Comment: Translating a client side file request to a server side file request will require restrictions on just what the client is allowed to request.

Comment: For example if I use this request: '../../../../<however deep root is>/../etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' and your system doesn't have any security in place, there is a really good chance I just got all of your Apache configurations.